# How to (programmatically) change slides in a running Keynote presentation?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, applescript, keynote

I'm working on a Cocoa application I'd like to use to remotely (on the same machine, from a different process) control which slide is currently displayed in a running Apple iWork '09 Keynote presentation.

How should I approach this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Keynote Applescript dictionary has an advance command. Using:

```
Tell application "Keynote" 
advance 
end tell
```

seems to do what you require. 
You can either use scripting bridge or NSApplescript to run this script from within a Cocoa application.

Comment: Perfect.  Thanks, Splash6.  I had checked Script Editor.app's Library, but I didn't see Keynote listed in there, so I assumed it didn't support AppleScript.

Comment: Instead of NSAppleScript, you might try OSAKit. Not only is it more full-featured, but NSAppleScript has a history of being leaky.